# Вывести числа в колонках

Tags: javascript

Вчера начал изучать js и тоже наткнулся на эту задачу. Просмотрев эту тему, написал код, но он выводит только последние цифры либо просто 11, в зависимости от того, куда поставить console.log. Возможно там много чего не так, хотелось бы получить помощь)
Так как рейтинг не позволяет загрузить на прямую, вот ссылка на мой код http://prntscr.com/4ladz2

Comment: > Так как рейтинг не позволяет загрузить на прямую, вот ссылка на мой код 

@vitalijzuj, для вставки кода не требуется особого уровня репутации. Достаточно воспользоваться кнопкой **{}** и отбить код от окружающего текста пустой строкой.

Ну, и если уж выкладываете код на другой ресурс, то хотя бы не картинкой. Есть же [pastebin.com](pastebin.com), [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) )

Comment: И у вас в коде, мне кажется, не все хорошо с фигурными скобками.